# How to compare the row and find the common value and uncommon values(using the comma) in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

This is my table

TableA

```
Id      Town     City     Country  
1        a         b         c  
1        a         b         d  
1        a         b         e  
2        f         g         h  
2        f         g         i  
2        f         g         j  
3        k         l         m
```

and in my jsp page this is how I need to display the data from table

```
          Title

Id      Town     City     Country  
1        a         b       c,d,e  
2        f         g       h,i,j  
3        k         l         m
```

I run the query (Select id, town, city, country from TableA). Then

```
public List<Place> getAddressChangeView () 
{
    List <Place> countriesList = new ArrayList < Place> ();

    List <Object[]> z = query.getResultList();

    List<String> countries = new ArrayList String;
    String delim ="," ;

    Place places = null;
    for (Object[] j: z)
    {

        places = new Place();
        int id = ((String) obj[0]);
        String town=((String) obj1);
        String city=((String) obj[2]);
        String country=((String) obj[3]);

        if (! id.equals(id1) && ! town.equals(town1) && ! city.equals(city1) && ! country.equals(country1)) 
        {
            id1= id;
            town1= town;
            city1=city;
            country1=country;

            places.setId(id);
            places.setTown(town);
            places.setCity(city);

        }

        countries.add(country);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s: countries)
        {
            sb.append(s).append(delim);

        }
        places.setCountry(sb.toString());

        countriesList.add(places);

    }

    return countriesList;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A common way to implement a grouping operation is with a `Map`. In other words you create a mapping from each group to a list of objects in that group. You can then iterate through the map to process each group. In your case it looks as though you are just grouping by ID (though that might just be the sample data you gave).

Using java 8 streams it would look like:

```
List<Place> places = table.stream()
    .map(Place::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<String, List<Place>> grouping = places.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Place::getID));
```

You can then easily iterate through the groups doing whatever you need to with them, including comma separated countries:

```
grouping.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
    String id = entry.getKey();
    List<Place> places = entry.getValue();
    String countries = places.stream()
        .map(Place::getCountry)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    ...
};
```

If you are grouping by something more complicated (such as grouping by Town and City at the same time) then you extend this solution by creating a grouping class:

```
class Group {
    private final String town;
    private final String city;
    public static Group forPlace(Place place) {
        return new Group(place.getTown(), place.getCity());
    }
}
```

Then the grouping statements become:

```
Map<Group, List<Place>> grouping = places.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Group::forPlace));
```

As the key of the map is now `Group` you can get the Town and City of the group as you iterate through the set of entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in your query like this using CTEs (one recursive) and a rank function in your SQL:

```
with Countries(Id, Town, City, Country, Seq) as (
  select Id, Town, City, Country,
    row_number() over(partition by Id order by Country)
  from TableA
), Maxes(Id, Seq) as (
  select Id, max(Seq) from Countries group by Id
), Recursed(Id, Town, City, Country, Seq) as (
  select Maxes.Id, Town, City, Country, Maxes.Seq
  from Countries, Maxes
  where Countries.Id = Maxes.Id and Countries.Seq = Maxes.Seq
  union all
  select c.Id, c.Town, c.City, c.Country || ',' || r.Country, c.Seq
  from Countries c, Recursed r
  where c.Id = r.Id and c.Seq = r.Seq - 1
)
select Id, Town, City, Country
from Recursed
where Seq = 1
order by Id
```

Assuming string concatenation operator `||`, this yields:

```
Id   Town  City  Country  
1     a      b    c,d,e  
2     f      g    h,i,j  
3     k      l      m
```